# azure-devops export work items as csv and include ALL comments/discussions

Tags: csv, azure-devops, export, comments

if I make a query in Azure Devops for my work items, when I add columns to display, there is only `comments count` and `discussions`, but is there any where to include all comments from a work item in my output saved csv file? I need to archive the comments for every work item in a csv.

Can I do this through the azure desktop web ui somehow? or do i need to write my own script using the azure api to view comments and add them to a work item

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this through the azure desktop web ui somehow? or do i need
> to write my own script using the azure api to view comments and add
> them to a work item

For your first question, the answer is **NO**. Since you want all the comments for a workitem, then built-in UI feature will not be able to achieve your requirement.

For your second the question, the answer is **YES**.

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import requests
import csv
import os
#get all the comments of a work item
def get_work_items_comments(wi_id):
    #get a connection to Azure DevOps
    organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx'
    personal_access_token = 'xxx'
    credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
    connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
    work_item_tracking_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
    #get the work item
    work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(wi_id)
    #get the comments of the work item
    comments_ref = work_item._links.additional_properties['workItemComments']['href']
    #send a request to get the comments
    response = requests.get(comments_ref, auth=('', personal_access_token))
    #get the comments
    comments = response.json()['comments']
    return comments

#return work item id, work item title and related work item comments
def get_work_items_results(wi_id):
    #get a connection to Azure DevOps
    organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx'
    personal_access_token = 'xxx'
    credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
    connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
    work_item_tracking_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
    #get the work item
    work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(wi_id)
    #get the title of the work item
    title = work_item.fields['System.Title']
    #get the work item id
    id = work_item.id
    #get the comments of the work item
    items = get_work_items_comments(wi_id)
    array_string = []
    for item in items:
        text = item['text']
        array_string.append(text)
        print(item['text'])
    return id, title, array_string

#Save the work item id, work item title and related work item comments to a csv file

#create folder workitemresults if not exist
if not os.path.exists('workitemresults'):
    os.makedirs('workitemresults')

with open('workitemresults/comments_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Workitem ID','Workitem Title','Workitem Comments'])

    #===if you want multiple work items, just for loop in this place and replace the value 120 in this place, 120 is the workitem id on my side.=== 

    writer.writerow(get_work_items_results(120))
```

The above code is to capture the comments and information for one workitem. It works fine on my side(The place for what 'for loop' should be placed I had already mentioned in my code, using the for loop in that place you can capture multiple workitems):

[image]

[image]

In my situation, if I only want the text content:

```
#remove <div> and </div> from the text
text = text.replace('<div>','')
text = text.replace('</div>','')
```

Result:

[image]